# Problems saving data to UserDefaults

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, userdefaults

I'm struggling with saving some date to UserDefaults. I have a struct, an array of which I'm going to save:

```
struct Habit: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()   
    var name: String
    var comments: String
}
```

Then, in the view, I have a button to save new habit to an array of habits and put it into UserDefaults:

```
struct AddView: View {
    @State private var newHabit = Habit(name: "", comments: "")
    @State private var name: String = ""
    let userData = defaults.object(forKey: "userData") as? [Habit] ?? [Habit]()
    @State private var allHabits = [Habit]()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Habit name")) {
                    TextField("Jogging", text: $newHabit.name)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Description")) {
                    TextField("Brief comments", text: $newHabit.comments)
                }
                
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("New habit")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                allHabits = userData
                allHabits.append(newHabit)
                defaults.set(allHabits, forKey: "userData")
            }) {
                addButton
            })
        }
    }
}
```

When I tap the button, my app crashes with this thread: `Thread 1: "Attempt to insert non-property list object (\n    \"HabitRabbit.Habit(id: 574CA523-866E-47C3-B56B-D0F85EBD9CB1, name: \\\"Wfs\\\", comments: \\\"Sdfdfsd\\\")\"\n) for key userData"`

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adopting `Codable` doesn't make the object property list compliant per se, you have to encode and decode the object to and from `Data`.

Something like this

```
func loadData() -> [Habit]
    guard let userData = defaults.data(forKey: "userData") else { return [] }
    return try? JSONDecoder().decode([Habit].self, from: userData) ?? []
}

func saveData(habits : [Habit]) {
    guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(habits) else { return }
    defaults.set(data, forKey: "userData")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!